# Get value of input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do anything with this one input box, but here I'm trying to extract the current text.

```js
console.log('running');
$('#kw-search').on('keyup', function (event) {
 var name = $(this).val();
 alert(name);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Keylines playaround</title>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />
  <!-- <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/uploader_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.qtip.min.css"> -->
  <!-- jquery  -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
  <!-- <script src="js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.filereader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- Keylines -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/keylines.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/keylines.setup.js"></script> -->
  <!-- google table -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['table']}]}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google-api.draw-tables.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="js/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script> -->
  <!-- Our main JS files -->
  <!-- <script src="js/uploader.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js/search.live.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="commands">
   <input type="text" id="kw-search">
  </div>
  <div id="phrases">
   
  </div>
  <div id="keywords">
   
  </div>
  <div id="file-upload">
   <div class="panel">
    <form id="upload" method="post" action="\cgi-bin\keylines\upload.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div id="drop">
      Drop Files Here

      <a>Browse</a>
      <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
     </div>

     <ul>
     </ul>
    </form>
   </div>
  <div class="pull-me">File Upload</div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="kl-container">
    <div id="kl" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;" ></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The javascript shown is from `search-live.js`. It works in this page but refuses to on my server. 
Most of the code above has been commented out to just get the input along with the uploader.
Any ideas?

Comment: `$(this).val()` is a massive overhead of `this.value`.

Comment: Wrap your code in a document ready handler or put it at the end of the page. You're using code on elements that don't exist at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either move your code to the end of the page, or wrap it in a [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

You're trying to execute code on elements that don't exist at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the code is not executed before the element kw-search is loaded, so wrapping it in the document read function will prevent that from happening

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log('running');
    $('#kw-search').on('keyup', function (event) {
    var name = $(this).val();
    alert(name);
    });
});
```